# Android Studio 2.2.2: Failed to resolve Google Play-Services

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, android-studio-2.2

I was trying to create a demo project based on Google Map, for this I was using MapsActivity provided by android studio. Everything is fine excluding the Google Play services. Android studio is failed to resolve play-services and throwing an error-

```
Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0
Install Repository and sync project
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog
```

**Project Gradle**

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

 buildscript {
 repositories {
    jcenter()
 }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
 }
}

allprojects {
 repositories {
    jcenter()
 }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**App Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mymapapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner  "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have the updated sdk tools **Google Play services v-33**  and  **Google Repository v-36**.
I tried many things to handle it, but still facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue, it was a bug on the repository link.

```
"Install Google Repository" failed.
 Failed packages:
- Google Repository (extras;google;m2repository)
```

Now the new link- https://dl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_gms_v7_rc28_wear_2a3.zip(at this time) working fine, I updated my google repository and google play-services and its work like a charm.

Comment: Does that link go in the "update sites" of the SDK tools Deepanshu? I just added it there and it killed my Android Studio! Could you provide more instructions as to how you fixed this? I am facing a very similar sounding issue -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294906/failed-to-resolve-com-google-android-gmsplay-services-location9-6-1