# Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1

Tags: android, google-maps, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, android-studio-2.2

Having updated to AS v2.2.2 I can no longer resolve the Google Play Services maps and location facets. The message I receive is;

> Error:(54, 27) Failed to resolve:
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1 Install Repository and sync project
> /Documents/workspace//Polaris/build.gradle">Show
>   in File
> Show in
>   Project Structure dialog

The install link does not work and I have uninstalled AS and reinstalled as well as having uninstalled Play Services and reinstalled the latest (v37 at the time of writing).

All out of ideas. I *do not* have the `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` and `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` bits and pieces that related questions suggest. I don't know what they are for so avoiding... plus, it worked on Android Studio v2.2 (at the same version 9.6.1).

Any help in getting my Google flavour to build again much appreciated.

Comment: If you look at the Gradle Console view, you may get more information about where it is looking for the artifacts. Does it appear to be looking in the right place?

Comment: Hi again @CommonsWare! Admittedly, I noted that unlike other q&a's around this same topic there is no mention in the stacktrace where gradle is  looking. Running; ````./gradlew assemble```` results in this output of nothingness! http://pastebin.com/gjdAmqec

Comment: (Polaris is a module in my app which abstracts the mapping provider allowing me to run against Google Maps or Open Street Maps) - perhaps this flavour based dependency configuration is factoring in? Seems unlikely I must admit.

Comment: Usually, the Gradle output in your pastebin shows where Gradle tried looking. Did you accidentally delete the `repositories` closure from your top-level `build.gradle` file (not the one in the `buildscript` closure, but the one in the `allprojects` closure)?

Comment: "I don't know what they are for so avoiding" ... They are for adding google play services to your classpath, so the classes contained within those dependencies can resolve. You **do** need them

Comment: @cricket_007 - ok. Is this a change with Play v9.6.+? Didn't read it in the release notes. Generally, the questions I'm reading are around Firebase and GCM where the solution is to add these plugins. Will go ahead and follow this guide... https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

Comment: I don't think it is specific to 9.6+, from the guide, *The google-services plugin has two main functions...*

Comment: Doesn't seem right. I don't use GA, Google sign-in or Push so it appears I don't need a ````google-services.json````...which is what this plugin drives off. Added it regardless and now have Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0 ! Just want maps, that's all! :D

Comment: @CommonsWare - phew, no all still in tact at the top level ````build.gradle````. http://pastebin.com/rLsWLiFh

Comment: And the module that is failing is applying either the `com.android.application` or `com.android.library` plugin?

Comment: @CommonsWare Polaris is a library, aiming for it to be my first vaguely useful open source-able lib. Here's it's ````build.gradle```` (thanks for helping both btw!) http://pastebin.com/MYPfDwAv

Comment: Well, I'm stumped at this point. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks for helping either way! @CommonsWare do you think I need to pursue adding play services to the classpath? Anyway, here's a trip down memory lane - Remember this? https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/05/22/remember-google-play-services-proprietary.html - This blog entry started me down the road of building my app for both Amazon-Android and Google-Android without feature compromise and the subsequent mapping abstraction library. What goes around....!

Comment: It's more that I can't explain your symptoms. If I were in your shoes, I would create a scrap application project. Add Maps to its `build.gradle`, see if it builds. If it does not, your build environment is borked, and we now have more to work with. If it does build, start progressively adding more stuff from your existing module's Gradle configuration (e.g., product flavors, Dagger), until you break the app's build -- whatever you changed last is probably the source of your difficulty.

Comment: good idea. I think my build env is broken - new app worked just fine and then upon adding gms play services it all went wrong again. I'll just have to burn this laptop then.... (facepalm)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by manually downloading Play Services as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40233397/1348379) and moving into position under the SDK.

:S

`#hacking4life`